# Функция вызывается с неправильными значениями переменных

Tags: c++, c, fft, обработка-сигналов

Суть вопроса такова. Есть такой код:

```
#include "stdafx.h"

#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
#define FR 3
#define SAMPLES 1024

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   base signal[SAMPLES];

   for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLES; ++i)
   {
       signal[i] = (sin(2*PI*i*FR), 0);
   }

   FFTCalculate(signal, SAMPLES, false);

   FILE* f_pointer = fopen("fft_result.txt", "w");

   for (int i = 0; i < SAMPLES; ++i)
   {
       char num = (char)signal[i].real();
       int out = fprintf(f_pointer, &num);
   }
   int out = fclose(f_pointer);
   return 0;
}
```

в нем вызывается функция FFTCalculate(signal, SAMPLES, false). Ниже приведен код функции:

```
void FFTCalculate(base signal[], int n, bool invert)
{   
int log_N;
double x = frexp((double)n, &log_N);

   calc_rev(n, log_N);

   for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
       if (i < rev[i])
               swap(signal[i], signal[rev[i]]);

   for(int len = 2; len <= n; len<<=1)
   {
       double ang = 2*PI/len * (invert?-1:1);
       int len2   = len>>1;

       base wlen (cos(ang), sin(ang));
       wlen_pw[0] = base(1, 0);
       for (int i=0; i<len2; ++i)
           wlen_pw[i] = wlen_pw[i-1] * wlen;

       for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
       {
           base t;
           base *pu = signal + i;
           base *pv = signal + i + len2;
           base *pu_end = signal + i + len2;
           base *pw = wlen_pw;

           for(; pu != pu_end; ++pu, ++pv, ++pu){
               t   = *pv * *pw;
               *pv = *pu - t;
               *pu += t;
           }
       }
    }
if(invert)
for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
signal[i] /= n;
}
```

При запуске программы появляется ошибка, связанная с выходом за пределы массива. Начал дебажить и выяснил, что когда вызывается функция `FFTCalculate(signal, SAMPLES, false)`, то ей почему то передаются не `signal, SAMPLES = 1024 и false`, а `sugnal, 1245452 и true` см. скриншот ниже. В чем дело?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а точно нигде больше не вызываете эту функцию в коде?

Comment: нет, точно больше нигде не вызывается, тем более первая точка остановки стоит внутри функции _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]), перед вызовом FFTCalculate(signal, SAMPLES, false).

Comment: Полный ребилд не помогает? А также, настройки precompiled headers одинаковые у всех файлов (кроме stdafx.cpp)?

Comment: есть подозрение, что SAMPLES ещё где то определен. Вот и выводит. Так как это с++, используйте const или для начала просто переименуйте define.

Comment: А почему тогда true в место false?

Comment: Какую библиотеку нужно прицепить для «base»?

Comment: @Kashchenko_P #define true false очень загадочная команда:)

Comment: Попробовал полный ребилд - не помогло. define переименовал, использовал const, даже пробовал тупо вызывать - FFTCalculate(signal, 1024, false). Не помогло всеравно получается n = 1245452 invert = true.

Comment: @Arik <complex> из STL

Comment: @KoVadim #define true false исключено )

Comment: У меня есть идеи, почему так, но нет времени собирать все эти куски воедино. Можете собрать минимально работающий файл с кодом, который повторит ошибку?

Comment: @KoVadim могу прям исходники выслать ))) проект маленький. _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]) написана специально что бы потестить FFTCalculate

Comment: не нужно говорить о том, что можно выслать. Нужно уже ссылку на любую файлопомойку приложить.

Comment: `signal[i] = (sin(2*PI*i*FR), 0);` Вот эта строчка меня смущает, синус то не вычисляется. Посмотрите вот этот пример  http://ideone.com/VN43hP

Comment: Если main и FFTCalculate положить в один файл, то такая же ошибка? / Подозреваю, что типы `base` в разных единицах компиляции *на самом деле разные*.

Comment: здесь исходники - https://yadi.sk/d/cYyD4Lnfh5VMQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я проверил на GCC 4.8.2 под linux. Параметры FFTCalculate передаются корректно. Думаю что, то поведение которое ты видишь в Visual Studio является unexpected behavior. Твоя программа под линуском сразу упала с seg fault.

Ниже пример кода с ошибкой.
Ты не проверяешь значения rev[i], что оно может быть больше n (1024).

```
   calc_rev(n, log_N);

   for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
       if (i < rev[i])
               swap(signal[i], signal[rev[i]]);
```

Вот что у меня вывелось для первых десяти итераций из массива rev:
0
1024
1536
1280
1792
1152
1664
1408
1920

Надеюсь помог.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Оказалось, что аргументы действительно передаются правильно, все дело было во включенной оптимизации кода. Проблема была вот где:

        `for(; pu != pu_end; ++pu, ++pv, ++pu){
                           t   = *pv * *pw;
                           *pv = *pu - t;
                           *pu += t;
                       }`
Два раза инкрементируется указатель pu и, как следствие выход за пределы массива.